# The use of finish() in a activity called by another activity makes the SideNavigationView fail in first activity

Tags: android, menu, android-activity

Lets say I have my common functions in a BaseActivity class (The SlideNavigationMenu functions) and I extend it in a News class which shows some links. When I click a link I open it in a CustomWebView class which is sort of a mini web browser. Now my back button is used to toggle slide menu so I have a handler for that in base class.

Note that both News and CustomWebView class extend the base activity class.

In the news class I do nothing and menu toggles.

In the CustomWebView class I rewrite the back button handler and call finish().

The strange thing happens when I am in News (initially) everything works fine, when I get to CustomWebView by entering a link and come back to news by pressing back button.. The News class than stops responding to back/menu/ any other gesture I left for toggling the menu.

I need help with this ?

Comment: can we see some code? Could help you out much better, without code my guess is your not re initializing your view again, what your saying is your view/activity shows up, but you cant touch it right?

Comment: **BaseActivity:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z35tt00wgygbugv/BaseActivity.java
**News:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pg0djro4ul46r4c/News.java
**CustomWebView:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqx7daq6bwr5k1i/CustomWebView.java

Though I managed to solve the problem in some time. I was silly. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

So silly of me.. I initialised the slide menu variable in the base class, it involved the context as "this". So, everything works initially and menu works but later when I enter the CustomWebView class the initialise function called in onCreate() sets context as "this" of CustomWebView class.

When I press back the prior activity is not reloaded but just shown.. so context is still of CustomWebView.

Just called the initialise() function in onResume of News class and I was good to go.